# Installing pip without internet

Tags: rhel, python, pip

I'm installing python3-pip~~.rpm on RHEL7.6 but got an error saying

```
/usr/bin/python3 is needed by python3-pip~~~.noarch
python(abi) = 3.6 is needed by python3 ~~~.noarch
```

The system came with python 2.7.5 pre-installed and I manually installed Python 3.9.0 from official python.org tar.gz file. Actually there is no /usr/bin/python3 but there exists /usr/local/bin/python3.

What should I do to get it work?

This system has no internet access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you installed Python 3.9 from source, you should have the [`ensurepip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html) module.

Simply run `python3 -m ensurepip` and you're done.

*On a side note, installing from source is not recommended because people usually don't keep their installs up-to-date, as is the case with Python 3.9.0.*